# Bernouilli Trials and Expectation

Tags: probability

Let a bernouilli trial have success probability $(0.2)$ and failure probability $(0.8)$

Let a random variable $X$ be the scenario where we have $x$ failures before a success given by probability mass function $f(x) = (0.8)^x(0.2)$.

Then I am trying to find $E[x]$ which I know by definition is equal to 
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i(0.8)^i(0.2)$. Is this correct because it seems that this would diverge to infinity and I'm not sure if that is an appropriate value.

Comment: What makes you think that diverges?  If $f(x)=\sum x^i=\frac 1{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$, then $f'(x)=\sum ix^{i-1}$ and that is now easy to compute.  (Note:  $xf'(x)=\sum ix^i$ to get the indices aligned).

Comment: it will not diverge, because $0.8<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall the standard *finite* evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag1
$$ by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ and *by making* $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, *using $|x|<1$*, one gets

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. \tag3
$$

Then apply $(3)$ with $x=0.8$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot0.8^n=\frac{0.8}{(1-0.8)^2}=20.
$$

Comment: How did you get from (2) to (3), i don't see where the $x$ in the numerator if from.

Comment: $(2)$ as $n \to \infty$ gives $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $ then, multiplying both sides by $x$, we obtain $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate method, we can do it recursively.

Consider what happens on the first trial. Either we get a success (probability $p=.2$) in which case $X=0$, or we don't and we are back in the same situation having recorded one fail.  Thus $$E=p\times 0+(1-p)\times (E+1)\implies E=\frac {1-p}p$$

Taking $p=.2$ gives $E=4$, as does the Geometric Series method.